# How to write a Javascript a function that runs every 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

for my discord.js bot i was trying to make it have a changing status message yet i cant get timers to work, so for now heres my basic code for the status, 
(this code makes the bots status say "Watching: You")

```js
client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  
        game: {
            name: "You",  
            type: "WATCHING" 
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: `console.log("Logged in"); setInterval(() => client.user.setPresence( ... ), 1000 * 60 * 30);`

Comment: oh thank you i needed that

Comment: @Chris Hey uh, now my bot doesnt have a status at all anymore

Comment: @Chris please help

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
let statuses = [
    {game: {name: `1`}, type: "WATCHING"},
    {game: {name: `2`}, type: "PLAYING"}
    {game: {name: `3`}, type: "STREAMING"}
];
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
     // Get the status
     let status = statuses[i];
     // If it's undefined, it means we reached the end of the array
     if(!status){
         // Restart at the first status
         status = statuses[0];
         i = 0;
     }
     client.user.setPresence(status);
     i++;
}, 5000);
```

Bot changes presence every 5 seconds

Comment: Also, you just need to change ``5000`` to ``1800000`` to have it change every 30 minutes